# Start movie playback on asys O!Play over telnet

Tags: linux, media-player, telnet

I hope this is the correct stackpage to ask this question.

I have an asus oplay mediaplayer next to my tv which offers a telnet interface.
Now i have built a nice app that indexes my media library and i thought it should be possible to make it send a command over telnet to the mediaplayer to start playing a certain movie.

I have been looking and the mediaplayer process seems to be called DvdPlayer, however the helptext is of no use.

Does anybody know if/how this can be done?